# What is the reverse of DataBind() function in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I am currently doing data binding with a grid view with a data source from an ArrayList. Is there a way to reverse the bind and get the value from the grid view with a one line code?

```
// Bind to GUI
ArrayList dsList;
gvName.DataSource = dsList;
gvName.DataBind();

// Current Way of getting code from GUI
int iRow = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvName.Rows)
{
    TextBox txtD1 = gvName.FindControl("textboxName") as TextBox;
    if (txtD1 != null) 
    {
        dsList[iRow].D1 = txtD1.Text;
    }
    ....
    iRow++;
}
```

Is there any way to make this shorter like one liner? Does the API have this?

```
gvName.ReverseDataBind();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No method like that exists in the API.

If you're interested in getting the binding source during the page construction, the best way to do this is to make the source a class-level property of the page itself so that it's available in any of the page's methods. For example:

```
public class MyPage: Page {
    ArrayList dsList = new ArrayList();

    ArrayList DsList {
        get {
            return this.dsList;
        }
}
```

If you're interested in getting the binding source on postbacks (in response to client-generated events), that is possible with some qualifications. Presuming you don't want to rebuild the binding source (for example, by re-querying a database, which should always be considered), you'll have to save it *somewhere* when you first get it so that you can access it later. (databound web controls do not do this themselves.) That somewhere can be a database, but sometimes for convenience, people save it to `ViewState` or store it in the `Session`. Both of these approaches have their hazards though and should be used with care - `ViewState` increases the size of the Html sent to the client and `Session` consumes server memory until it's explicitly cleared or the session times out.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the *real* answer is to use a `BindingList<T>` instead of an array as this takes care of all the two-way communications between the list and the binding so you won't have to manually update the list from the grid.

However, if you can't use a `BindingList<T>`, the best you can do is retrieve the databound item from the row:

```
// Bind to GUI
ArrayList dsList;
dgvName.DataSource = dsList;
dgvName.DataBind();

// Slightly simpler way of getting code from GUI
int iRow = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in gvName.Rows)
{    
    object item = dgvr.DataBoundItem;        
    dsList[iRow].D1 = item.ToString();

    iRow++;
}
```

The DataBoundItem value returned can be cast to the appropriate type for processing, which is slightly simpler that searching for a text box control.

Comment: DataBoundItem can only return the first control in the row right?

Comment: Also the DataGridViewRow is only applicable to windows application and not ASP .NET application which has the GridViewRow object. The GridViewRow object does not have a DataBoundItem.

Comment: Apologies, I read it as DataGridViewRow and thought it was for Winforms.  Perhaps if you put ASP.NET in the title, it might attract more web devs.

Comment: Thanks Dr Herbie I just changed the title.